# How to animate all the menu icons like lottie animation?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-navigation, android-navigationview

I want to animate all the items of the navigation drawer continuously like Lottie animations.
Is it possible to animate them all continuously?

These are my menu items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        android:iconTint="#6200EA"
        android:title="@string/home"
        tools:targetApi="o" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_expert_tips"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_tips_and_updates_24"
        android:iconTint="#6200EA"
        android:title="@string/expert_tips"
        tools:targetApi="o" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_most_selling"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_sell_24"
        android:iconTint="#6200EA"
        android:title="@string/most_selling"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24"
        android:iconTint="#6200EA"
        android:title="@string/share_it"
        tools:targetApi="o" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_rate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_rate_24"
        android:iconTint="#6200EA"
        android:title="@string/rate_us"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_contact_support_24"
        android:iconTint="#6200EA"
        android:title="@string/contact_us"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

</group>
```

How to animate these all items in the navigation drawer?